# Printing file name and file path to a csv

Tags: python

I am new to programming and am not sure of the best way to achieve my end goal.

I would like to create a script that will walk through a directory tree with hundreds of systematically named image files and then print the file names and file paths to a csv.

I understand how to use os.walk to list all images however I not sure how best to achieve my final output, e.g. should I create two lists (one with the file names and one with the file paths) or is there a better method for collecting my data for export to csv?

```
path = '/Users/User/Photos/'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for x in files:
        file_path= os.path.join(root, x)
        print(file_path)
        file_name= os.path.basename(x)
        print(file_name)
```

Can somebody please point me towards the best method for printing the file_name and file_path pairs to a csv?

Comment: have you looked at the `csv` module of python? https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Why not just combine the two into a single unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
import os


path = '/Users/User/Photos/'
with open('tree.csv', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write('file_name,file_path\n')
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for x in files:
            file_path= os.path.join(root, x)
            file_name= os.path.basename(x)
            fout.write('{},{}\n'.format(file_name, file_path))
```

A csv file will be created under the name `tree.csv` that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I added a line, os.chdir(path), to allow me to set the destination of the csv! Thank you Anwarvic

Comment: Glad, I could help :)

Comment: Can I run this code in the future, after new images have been added to the directory? Will this edit the csv and add any new file names and paths or will the code need editing to prevent errors?

Comment: Yes, you can run it after adding as many images as you wish with no problem.